# How to convert QList to QSet in Qt 6

Tags: c++, list, qt, set, qt6

I am porting my application to Qt 6 and as I am reading documentation I see that classes are cleaned up a lot, `QList` and `QVector` are unified, `QStringList` is now alias to `QList<QString>` and so on.

But now this gave me one problem.

In my code (which is Qt 5) I am converting `QStringList` to `QSet` to eliminate duplicates from the list. I went through new documentation but I haven't seen a way to convert `QList` to `QSet` in Qt 6.

So how do you convert `QList` to `QSet`? Or it is not possible and I will need to write a helper function for removing duplicates?

EDIT: I am using Qt 6.0.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I must admit that I'm still on Qt5.

However, `QList` and `QSet` remind me strong to `std::list` and `std::set`.
For the latter, there was already another (and more flexible) way to achieve such things:
using construction with iterators. A short check in the Qt6 doc. convinced me, this should work in the Qt classes as well:

**[QSet::QSet(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qset.html#QSet-2)**

> Constructs a set with the contents in the iterator range [first, last).
>
> The value type of InputIterator must be convertible to T.
>
> **Note:** If the range [first, last) contains duplicate elements, the first one is retained.
>
> This function was introduced in Qt 5.14.

where `first` is set with

**[QList::iterator QList::begin()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlist.html#begin)**

> Returns an STL-style iterator pointing to the first item in the list.

and `last` with

**[QList::iterator QList::end()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlist.html#begin)**

> Returns an STL-style iterator pointing to the imaginary item after the last item in the list.

How this should look like when put together:

```
QList<QString> aList;
// populate list
QSet<QString> aSet(aList.begin(), aList.end());
```

---

OP noted that the Qt-5 doc. already contained a hint concerning this:

**[QSet QList::toSet() const](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#toSet)**

> **Note:** Since Qt 5.14, range constructors are available for Qt's generic container classes and should be used in place of this method.

OP also mentioned a convenience wrapper:

```
template <typename T>
QSet<T> QListToQSet(const QList<T>& qlist)
{
  return QSet<T> (qlist.constBegin(), qlist.constEnd());
}
```

applied to the above sample:

```
QList<QString> aList;
// populate list
QSet<QString> aSet = QListToQSet(aList);
```

A more general conversion facility would probably be something like this:

```
template <typename T, template<typename> typename C>
QSet<T> toQSet(const C<T> &container)
{
  return QSet<T>(container.begin(), container.end());
}
```

which would work even with matching `std` containers as well:

```
std::vector<QString> aVec = { "Hello", "World", "Hello" };
QSet<QString> aSet = toSet(aVec);
```

Answer (score -1):

you are right, see in the [code](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-6/qstringlist.html#details) or the [doc](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-6/qstringlist.html#details) that  QStringList is a child of QList

```
class QStringList : public QList<QString>
{
```

so you can call  QSet toSet() const; directly since the method is public.

with this, you can unzip directly the content of the **QStringlist** to a **qset**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString str = "one,two,three,four,one";
    QStringList strlt = str.split(QChar(','));

    const QSet<QString> strVe = strlt.toSet();
    qDebug() << strVe;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: `QStringList` doesn't have `toSet` on it any more, unfortunately.